# Java, CData and multiple xslt transformations

Tags: java, xslt, transform

I've read/googled a lot on xslt and CDATA.

I have no control over the original data (in the database).
Here is my problem, as the data flows:
A) The xslt file (when loaded by the first transformer) calls a Java function that retrieves and transforms the data from the database. Snippet of the the xslt file:

```
<xsl:stylesheet xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml" 
...[more xmlns]... 
version="2.0" xmlns:fn="http://www.w3.org/2005/xpath-functions"
exclude-result-prefixes="#all"> 
<xsl:output method="xhtml" omit-xml-declaration="yes" indent="no"/>
...[some xsl:includes]...
<xsl:variable name="myVar" select="resource:getFaq('some value')" />
<xsl:template match="/">
...[some business logic]...
    <xsl:template name="someTemplate">
        ...
        <xsl:for-each select="$myVar/faq/entry">
            ...
            <ui:cell>   
                <xsl:copy-of select="value/answer" />
            </ui:cell>
...[a lot more stuff]...
```

B) Data from database:

```
...
<answer><![CDATA[<p>Enter the...<some html tags>...needs.</p>]]></answer>
...
```

C) First transformation inside **getFaq** results in (manual traverse print out of the org.w3c.dom.Node):

```
...
<answer><#cdata-section><p>Enter the...<some html tags>...needs.</p></#cdata-section></answer>
...
```

D) The xslt file transformation result (using the data from **getFaq**):

```
...  
<ui:cell><answer><#text><p>Enter the...<some html tags>...needs.</p></#text></answer></ui:cell>
...
```

E) The xslt file gets transformed by another process and the result is:

```
...
<td class="ui-cell "><answer xmlns="" xmlns:ui="http://www.somewhere.com/ui"><![CDATA[<p>Enter the...<some html tags>...needs.</p>]]></answer></td>
...
```

F) What the browser (Firefox 6.0.2) displays:

```
...
<td class="ui-cell "><answer xmlns:ui="http://www.somewhere.com/ui" xmlns=""><!--[CDATA[<p-->Enter the...<some html tags>...needs.</p>]]&gt;</answer></td>
...
```

The issue is that CDATA is changed to Text data from step **C** to **D**. The output method must be **xhtml**

Answer (score 0):

If your XSLT result is serialized as XML by the XSLT processor and you want the contents of certain elements to be serialized as CDATA sections then you need to tell that to the processor in `xsl:output` directive http://www.w3.org/TR/xslt20/#serialization e.g.

```
<xsl:output cdata-section-elements="answer"/>
```

But this, as I a said, is a serialization feature, your description sounds a bit as if your transformation creates nodes and does not serialize them.